# WP add_action factory

Tags: php, plugin-development

Hello I am new to WP and PHP, I am trying to create a class that takes **(maybe) an array of arrays**, then used to **generate N° add_action for each array passed**.

Example:

```
[
  array(
  "name" => "my_custom_action",
  "cb" => "function(){return true;}" 
)
]
```

This is the code I wrote until now.

```
class Actions {

    public function __construct($actions){
      $this->actions = $actions;

      foreach($this->actions as $action){
        add_action($action['name'], $action['cb']);
      }
    }

  }
```

I was reading about the `create_function()` method, but it's deprecated.

I would like to understand how to **create multiple add_action** with a single call basically, instead of writing every time the function and then add the action in the constructor.

I also found this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

It's used to generate functions instead of using `create_function()`, but I do not understand it very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the php [callable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) manual.

> A PHP function is passed by its name as a string. Any built-in or user-defined function can be used, except language constructs such as: array(), echo, empty(), eval(), exit(), isset(), list(), print or unset().

However, in your code sample you are using an anonymous function, which can be passed directly.

`[
  array(
  "name" => "my_custom_action",
  "cb" => function(){return true;} 
)
]`

Comment: Thank you very much for the info mate.